# Why label and text in a small size simple form cannot align in a line?

Tags: sapui5

the label and text in the simpleform are in two lines.

I want them to align in a single line, I've tried to set properties like columns and labelSpan, but I need help to align them in a line.

```xml
<layout:DynamicSideContent
    class="sapUiDSCExplored sapUiContentPadding sapUxAPObjectPageSubSectionAlignContent" sideContentFallDown="BelowM" sideContentPosition="Begin">
    <layout:sideContent>
        <ScrollContainer vertical="true" focusable="true">
            <List id="list" mode="SingleSelectMaster" sticky="HeaderToolbar" 
                          items="{store>/items}">
            <items>
                <CustomListItem>
                <content>
                    <form:SimpleForm title="{store>p1}" 
                                          editable="false"    
                                          layout="ColumnLayout">
                                          <form:content>
                                              <Label/>
                                              <Text/>
                                          </form:content>
                    </form:SimpleForm>
                </content>
                </CustomListItem>
            </items>
            </List>
        </ScrollContainer>
    </layout:sideContent>
</layout:DynamicSideContent>
```

I created a [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/kai-xin-zhong/pen/KKrmaZZ) for preview

Comment: Check it with: layout="GridLayout"